# logging out on a netsuite sitebuilder ssp page without a redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, netsuite

Is there a way to log a user out of Netsuite's website without a redirect?  I want the user to remain on the same page but all of the session information to go away.  I have tried a few methods of deleting out all of the cookies, but so far have yet to find one that will delete everything, and `<%=nlapiGetWebContainer().getShoppingSession().logOut()%>` tries to redirect you to another page (as does all of the other netsuite help suggestions I have found so far.

In `IE` the following does exactly what I want but I haven't found a similar thing for `firefox` or `chrome`:

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of NetSuite, what if you loaded the page that calls ``<%=nlapiGetWebContainer().getShoppingSession().logOut()%>`` inside off-screen iframe? Then it redirects inside frame and the frame can be removed from the DOM later.

Comment: That is a good thought, the integration I am working on doesnt allow iframes though.

Comment: Not sure, but you can check this out : http://www.chenblog.xyz/questions/11491/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication